# How can i get access to unshared folder

Tags: c#, network-programming

I have an unshared folder on server and i want to access to it from clients by c# code.Is there any way to do this? If yes how?

please help
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are a admin (or domain admin) then you can use the implicitly shared C$.

If the file is at 'c:\foo\bar.html' on server named myserver, then try this:

```
   \\myserver\c$\foo\bar.html
```

Note that this only works when you are an administrator of the server.

Comment: do you suggest remote desktop?if yes how can i use it?

Comment: I am connecting to the server using an administrator account of the server but I get access denied

Answer (score 2):

If it's not shared, then you can't. - the server owner / admin chose (implicitly or explicitly) to not allow clients from other machines to access it. You'll need to contact the server owner to get the folder you need shared (possibly with some ACLs to limit who can access it).

Comment: Not always true, see my answer.